# MYSQL format string to number

Tags: mysql, sql

How to format string to number in mysql.

In example,

Convert value 1,222,333.22 to result: 1222333.22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `CAST()`

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(colName, ',', '') AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/061ff/1)